# Command cannot use as root in Amazon Linux in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using aws ec2 (Amazon Linux), and I'm in trouble.

I installed git flow, and I can use `git flow init` command as ec2-user.

But I cannot use `git flow init` as root user.

I don't understand why.....

Answer (score 0):

if you need run as root, sudo it.

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/git flow init
```

But from your description, the problem is something else.

Anyway, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for commenting.I did "sudo git flow init", but if I do it, "command not found" happens. Why??

Comment: can you run `which sudo` and `which git`, what do you get?

Comment: If I command  `which sudo`, `/usr/bin/sudo`. And If I command `/usr/bin/git` , `/usr/bin/git`.